# Sed not expanding * in variables

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed

I am working on a script that involves paths with wildcards.  I know the wildcards will match one file only, I just don't know what the file extension will be ahead of time so I am using a wildcard.

The goal here is to find the path to the appropriate file, and then add that path to line 16 of a script.

I have something like this:

```
path=/path/to/somewhere/fileName*

sed "16 a file=$path" myScript.sh
```

What I expect to get is this (on line 16):

```
file=/path/to/somewhere/fileName.extension
```

But what I get is:

```
file=/path/to/somewhere/fileName*
```

For some reason sed is not expanding the wildcard when it adds the contents of `$path` and I can't figure out how to make sed do such a thing.  I'm looking for a solution that either a) has sed properly expand `$path` or b) a way to get `$path` to contain the fully expanded string before being passed to sed.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable contains just a string and you then interpolate that string. `sed` can't know that's not what you mean. If you want the shell (not `sed`!) to expand the wildcard, probably use a loop.

```sh
for path in /path/to/somewhere/fileName*; do
   if [ -e "$path" ]; then   # handle wildcard possibly not matching
      sed "16 a file=$path" myScript.sh
   fi
done
```

It's unclear what should happen if the wildcard matches multiple files; perhaps you want to add a `break` before `fi` to only substitute the first one if that happens.

Comment: The computer probably doesn't know that, so the code should do the right thing even when it doesn't.

Comment: Good catch on what I thought was the solution, which I've now deleted because it wasn't correct.

Comment: A loop is an interesting solution.  Is there a simpler way to get bash to expand/interpolate the string?

Comment: You could put it in an array, for example.

Comment: @tripleee : Your suggestion how to fix it, is correct of course, but I think your explanation of the problem catches it only halfway: In bash, the assignement `path=/path/to/somewhere/fileName*` would already undergo pathname expansion. The fact that `file` still has an asterisk, means that there were no matching files. While it is right that this is unrelated to `sed`, the havoc occurs earlier already.

Comment: @user1934428 No, that's not correct. https://ideone.com/di5VT9

Comment: @tripleee : Uh, you'r right. Silly me - when I tried to recreate it, I forgot quoting the variable when printing it.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed, echo and bash):

```
export path='/path/toSomeWhere/filename*'
sed '16{s/$/\na file=$(echo $path)/;s/.*/echo "&"/e}' file
```

Export the variable `path` which has been set to `/path/toSomeWhere/filename*` (notice the single quotes which prevents interpolation).

On line 16 of `file` append a line `a file=$(echo $path)` and then surround both lines by double quotes and prepend the `echo` command and evaluate (the `e` flag on the second substitution command) the expression.

Alternative:

```
sed '17e echo "a file=$(echo /path/toSomeWhere/filename*)"' file
```